Нужно написать функцию сложения, чтобы она могла суммировать числа из списка и кортежа, например: ([1,2,3],4)
я новичок в Python. Пытаюсь написать функцию, чтобы она работала подобно sum и могла складывать числа из списка и кортежа, код ниже выдает ошибку 'int' object is not iterable, на конкретном примере цифра 4 идет в блок if, а е в elif, не могу понять почему так происходит.
В результате при вводе ([1,2,3],4) должен быть результат 10.
p.s. хотелось бы решить задачу базовыми способами, не используя что-то сложное
def mysum(*numbers):
    res = 0
    for i in numbers:
        if isinstance(numbers, (list, tuple)):
            for var in i:
                res += var
        elif isinstance(numbers, int):
            res += arg
    print(res)
mysum([1,2,3],4)


Подскажи, какое число ты подразумеваешь под arg ?

def mysum(*numbers):
    res = 0
    for i in numbers:
        if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
            for var in i:
                res += var
        elif isinstance(i, int):
            res += i
    print(res)
mysum([1,2,3],4)


Нужно проверять не numbers на соответствие, а i
Откуда вы взяли переменную arg? (Заменил её на i)

Теперь работает:

10
[Program finished]



arg должна быть i, осталась от прошлого варианта решения(
Спасибо за ответ!

